# Weird issue in Lazy load

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I am totally confused with one issue Spring data + hibernate

We have a Restful service which we are migrating to V2.

So the old controller looks like

```
@Api(tags = {"assignments"})
@RestController
@CheckedTransactional
public class AssignmentListController {

  @Inject
  private AssignmentListService assignmentListService;

  //REST function
  public list() {....}
}
```

The REST function list calls AssignmentListService to load assignments, which is a collection, and loads some data lazily. Its works excellent.

What I did is I copied this controller as name AssignmentListControllerV2, and it looks like

```
@Api(tags = {"assignments"})
@RestController
@CheckedTransactional
public class AssignmentListControllerV2 {
  @Inject
  private AssignmentListService assignmentListService;

  @Inject
  private AssignmentDtoMapper assignmentDtoMapper;

  public list() {...}
}
```

The code is same except AssignmentDtoMapper bean added, which is created using MapStruct.

Now the problem, When I call this new service, somehow I get a Lazy Load exception. The error is

> could not initialize proxy - no Session

I desperately need some help as I have no clue whats happening. I have just copied the code in a new class and its failing.

Comment: I guess it would be nice if you share some more code. Your Entity, Service method, and explain how does it get converted before sending all this back to client (in both versions). What does you mapper do?

Comment: The code is so big that I cannot share, also its an existing app, and I not sure if I can share its code due to privacy, and also I doubt if the service code makes any difference as same code works fine in V1.

Comment: Apparently the exception turned out to be different. Those Lazy objects were never loaded as part of the default query, but there was an Aspect defined that was setting up that data later on the object. The fact that the aspect was set on a pattern **.*Controller.**, and unfortunately the name of my Controller was ControllerV2, and this caused the problem. Thanks for helping out anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is actually pretty clear, Hibernate can't load the lazy fetched member because there is no persistence context open when you hit it.

I suppose that in the V2 the:

```
@Inject
private AssignmentDtoMapper assignmentDtoMapper;
```

is to change some JPA business entity into DTO?
It's probably the source of the exception if you try to map not loaded member there.

If you want to avoid the exception on unitiliazed proxy you can try something like

```
public boolean isProxyInitialized(Object obj){
    if(obj instanceof HibernateProxy){
        HibernateProxy proxy = (HibernateProxy) obj;

        return !proxy.getHibernateLazyInitializer().isUninitialized();
    }

    return obj != null;   
}
```

It should return true if the member as bean fetched otherwise false.

Comment: Apparently the exception turned out to be different. Those Lazy objects were never loaded as part of the default query, but there was an Aspect defined that was setting up that data later on the object. The fact that the aspect was set on a pattern **.*Controller.*, and unfortunately the name of my Controller was ControllerV2, and this caused the problem. Thanks for helping out anyways.